# System freezes when using vgaswitcheroo

Tags: laptop, radeon, hybrid-graphics, vgaswitcheroo

I'm using hybrid graphics on my notebook. It has an integrated Intel and a discrete Radeon HD 6650M graphic card.

When I want to switch to discrete card, the screen freezes and I can't do anything.

I chowned `/sys/kernel/debug/vga_switcheroo/switch` to my username. But when I use the following command, the system freezes after restarting X:

```
echo DDIS > /sys/kernel/debug/vga_switcheroo/switch
```

My question is: How can I switch to the Radeon card?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: Exact same case for me. I logged a bug at the linux kernel bug tracker and the Ubuntu bug tracer. Does not seem to make any difference though. It has not been updated for half a year now.